# Best way to handle redirects

Tags: redirect

I have number of pages that have had the urls changed, how can I setup a list of old urls and set the new urls they should point to?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 2):

[This plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/) does the job very well.

Answer (score 1):

Try these plugins:

**quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin** (set redirects manually)

**Permalink Finder** (finds missing pages and redirects to most likely candidate)

I use them together and they work great. I used to use the "Page Links To" plugin as mentioned above, which works ok but with the quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin plugin you can create redirects all from one screen and you don't have to create unneccessary pages.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the "Page Links To" plugin in successfully in the past to redirect old pages.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/page-links-to/

You'd have to create pages or posts with the old URL to the new URL and specify the new URL at the bottom of the editor page.

Answer (score 0):

or if you'd like a non-plugin solution, the synta your `.htaccess` file is (for a 301 permanent redirect):

```
RedirectPermanent /path/to/old-url /the-path/to/the-new-url
```